# Using a 555 timer and 14-stage binary divider for 2 hour timing circuit

Tags: relay, 555, frequency-divider

I am researching how to design a timing circuit that will activate a relay with a push button and deactivate the relay after two hours. My understanding is that I can feed the output of a 555 timer to the input of a 14-stage binary divider. Then feed the dividers' output to a relay driver. Then, after two hours of the divider receiving pulses, its output will change thus changing the state of the relay drivers output.

My question is, can a 555 timer reliably produce a ~1Hz pulse? And if so, will this be too low of a frequency for a binary divider to reliably handle?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use something based on a crystal, not a 555 timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 1Hz is a reasonable frequency for the 555, especially for the CMOS version. But it may not be optimal.

The temperature stability as an astable multivibrator is typically [+/-150ppm/°C](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf) for the bipolar version, **provided** the Ra is between 1K and 100K. To stay in that range, implies a capacitor of the order of 10uF, which is a large and expensive film capacitor or a tantalum capacitor. It will operate with higher resitances, but the stability will generally be worse.

Various CMOS versions such as the [LMC555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf) have improved temperature stability (+/-75ppm/°C typical) and you could us a resistor more in the 1M range and therefore a 1uF film capacitor or even 10x 100nF NP0 ceramic capacitors in parallel.

If you're using the bipolar version it might make more sense to add divider stages and operate at a higher frequency such as 50-200Hz. It also makes it easier to trim the oscillator if you have a reciprocal-counting frequency meter.

---

As to whether the dividers will work- yes, they're virtually all static and will work down to DC provided the clock edges meet specifications. The only exceptions that come to mind are GHz-range prescalers that won't work at lower frequencies (like < 50 or even 500 MHz). 
If the divider you pick does not have a schmitt-trigger input then the rise and fall times may have to be fairly fast, but the 555 will produce adequate edges generally.

Answer (score 0):

555 runs between  100kHz to 0.1Hz in a-stable mode. And depending of your divider (check datasheets some have only a inpulse input so they are not dependant of a frequency CD4020 I think) ; so this will just work as low as 1hz or lower

a good practice when you are not sure about precision is to use in circuit trimmers & variable-capacitors to get high precision around limits until it fix any bugs.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for at least not trying to do it without the divider. Pick a number that will give you a possibility of calibrating the 555. If you divide by 2<sup>13</sup> then a 1.138 s clock will give you two hours and it would be reasonably easy to calibrate and adjust using a stopwatch over ten cycles or so.

From what I can see the 555 has a temperature stability of 50 parts per million (ppm) per degree Celsius change in temperature which is equivalent to 0.005 %/°C. Build this into your calculations along with drift of the timing capacitors and resistors and you can check if it is good enough for you.

> My question is, can a 555 timer reliably produce a ~1Hz pulse? And if so, will this be too low of a frequency for a binary divider to reliably handle?

No problem for both questions.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is a 4060 which has 14 stages and two inverters you can use as an oscillator, making the 555 unnecessary.